# Decode stored JSON value in Database result in result_array()

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to extract value from json stored in db, but i cannot figure it out.
here's my db looks like :

```
+-------------------+-------------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| refid             |                      kepribadian                | jam_mulai           | jam_selesai         |
+-------------------+-------------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| GAD25D335B0F1DE3B | {"Introversion":"53.3%","Extroversion":"46.7%"} | 2019-08-09 01:16:00 | 2019-08-09 01:19:46 |
| GAD25D32DAE90578A | {"Introversion":"63.3%","Extroversion":"34.7%"} | 2019-08-09 08:55:47 | 2019-08-09 08:56:48 |
+-------------------+-------------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

And this is my models :

```
public function filter_hasil_mbti($search, $limit, $start, $order_field, $order_ascdesc)
{

    $sql =  $this->db->select('a.id AS id, a.refid AS refid, CONCAT(b.firstname," ",b.lastname) AS fullname, a.kepribadian AS kepribadian, a.jam_mulai AS jam_mulai, a.jam_selesai AS jam_selesai, a.percentage AS percentage')
            ->from('jawaban_mbti as a')
            ->join('registrasi_baru as b', 'a.refid=b.refid', 'left')
            ->like('a.refid', $search)
            ->or_like('b.firstname', $search)
            ->or_like('b.lastname', $search)
            ->or_like('a.kepribadian', $search)
            ->or_like('a.jam_mulai', $search)
            ->or_like('a.jam_selesai', $search)
            ->order_by($order_field, $order_ascdesc)
            ->limit($limit, $start)
            ->get()->result_array();

    return $sql;
}
```

So, I can access column kepribadian json as key and store it all in result_array()
How can i do that?

Thank you.

**UPDATE**

Here's my controller :

```
public function ajax_jawaban_mbti()
{
    $search         = $_POST['search']['value'];
    $limit          = $_POST['length'];
    $start          = $_POST['start'];
    $order_index    = $_POST['order'][0]['column'];
    $order_field    = $_POST['columns'][$order_index]['data'];
    $order_ascdesc  = $_POST['order'][0]['dir'];

    $sql_total      = $this->mhasil->count_all_Soal('jawaban_mbti');
    $sql_data       = $this->mhasil->filter_hasil_mbti($search, $limit, $start, $order_field, $order_ascdesc);
    $sql_filter     = $this->mhasil->count_filter_hasil_mbti($search);

    //print_r($sql_data);die;

    $callback       = array(
        'draw'              => $_POST['draw'],
        'recordsTotal'      => $sql_total,
        'recordsFiltered'   => $sql_filter,
        'data'              => $sql_data,
    );

    //header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($callback);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use json_decode to convert it to a array like bellow:

**Example:**

```
 $json = '{"Introversion":"53.3%","Extroversion":"46.7%"}';
 $array = json_decode($json)
 var_dump($array);
```

I suggest to change the name of the variable from $sql to $results because you return a array and not the sql

**update 1:**

```
foreach ($sql as $key => $val) {
// you can add in the second argument of json_decode 1 to have a array instead of a object.
if(isset($val['kepribadian']))
    $sql[$key]['kepribadian'] = json_decode($val['kepribadian']);
}
```

the result wil be like this:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [kepribadian] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Introversion] => 53.3%
                    [Extroversion] => 46.7%
                    [Sense] => 66.7%
                    [Intuition] => 33.3%
                    [Thingking] => 46.7%
                    [Feeling] => 53.3%
                    [Judging] => 66.7%
                    [Perceiving] => 33.3%
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1337
            [refid] => GAD25D335B0F1DE3B
            [fullname] => Ravhi Rizaldi
            [kepribadian] => 
            [jam_mulai] => 2019-08-09 01:16:00
            [jam_selesai]] => 2019-08-09 01:19:46
        )

)
```

Comment: how to decode it when the data is on the result_array()? it's like array in the array and thanks for your sugestion :)

Comment: can you give me a print_r of the result in the description ? the structure

Comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( [kepribadian] => {"Introversion":"53.3%","Extroversion":"46.7%","Sense":"66.7%","Intuition":"33.3%","Thingking":"46.7%","Feeling":"53.3%","Judging":"66.7%","Perceiving":"33.3%"} ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 1337 [refid] => GAD25D335B0F1DE3B [fullname] => Ravhi Rizaldi [kepribadian] => [jam_mulai] => 2019-08-09 01:16:00 [jam_selesai] => 2019-08-09 01:19:46 ) )

Comment: I got this error : A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined offset: 0

Comment: yes i have also updated my reponse update 1, try it

Comment: Thanks, I will try it later, brb.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you will get an array of data from your select statement where the "kepribadian" column is one of the values. So what you have to do is the DECODE this column from JSON to a PHP array.

In principle like this, (not tested)

```
...
$sqlrec = filter_hasil_mbti(...  ...);
$phpArr = json_decode($sqlrec['kepribadian']);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
<?php
    $json_decoded = json_decode(array_column($rsult, "kepribadian"), true);
 ?>
```

> If you add `true` parameter in `json_decode()` the result will be given as a PHP array.

Have fun :)